# Javascript - Perform several functions in a row && Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

I have created in my project several separate functions in separate files that I import with `module.exports.$functionName`

I then compile everything in an index.js file. This is the problem. The first function allows to download a file, without which the two other functions can't work. I tried to use the promises to wait for the download, but the file does not download and this error appears:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Here is the code, I specify that each function works when you run them independently:

```
const mt = require("./mainTweet"); // from mainTweet.js 
const rp = require("./Reply"); // from Reply.js
const od = require("./getcsv") // from getcsv.js

function Download() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    od.onDownload();
    resolve();
  });
}

function firstTweet() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    mt.getData()
    resolve();
  });
}

function secondTweet() {
  rp.Reply();
}

async function Launch() {
  await Download();
  await FirstTweet();
  Reply();
}

Launch();
```

Comment: Are `od.onDownload`, `mt.getData` and `rp.Reply` also async? Do they return promises?

Comment: yeah they are async

Answer (score 0):

Since you answered in a comment that `od.onDownload`, `mt.getData` and `rp.Reply` are async, the problem is that you do not `await` them.

When you do this:

```js
od.onDownload()
resolve()
```

`onDownload()` will run and return a promise immediately and then you resolve your own promise. This means that `onDownload` has not yet resolved (or thrown). You should instead await each call. You could simplify your whole code to this:

```js
const mt = require("./mainTweet"); // from mainTweet.js 
const rp = require("./Reply"); // from Reply.js
const od = require("./getcsv") // from getcsv.js

async function Launch() {
  await od.Download();
  await mt.getData();
  rp.Reply()
}

Launch();
```